# Can you tell me the difference of using list with index and without index?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

Tell me the difference and benefits of u both using list with index and list without index?

```
li=[1,2,'ayush',9,10,11,'yaman']

for i in range(len(li)):
    print(li[i])

for ele in li:
    print(ele)
```

Comment: Differences: none. Benefits of using the index form: none.

Comment: Which of the two involved less typing?

Comment: Loop with range is similar to normal for loop in java, loop without range is foreach loop in java

Comment: Lookup `enumerate` in your Python manual to use a combination of both,

Comment: Using an index looks more complicated and is slower.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in first case you can modify the original list and in the second case you cannot:

```
li=[1,2,'ayush',9,10,11,'yaman']

for ele in li:
    ele = 1
print(li)

for i in range(len(li)):
    li[i] = 1
print(li)
```

yields

```
[1, 2, 'ayush', 9, 10, 11, 'yaman']
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I suggest you read about Python [lists](https://thispointer.com/6-ways-to-get-the-last-element-of-a-list-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the mentioned fact that if you are not iterating over the list, but using indices instead, you are able to modify it on the fly, there is a slight speed advantage when iterating over the list directly.

This is because, if you use range(), Python constructs a fresh iterator, or in Python's 2.x case, another list, which takes extra time. Then, in each loop iteration, you are accessing a new index again and again. Random access in Python lists is very fast, but, if you iterate directly over the list, Python makes you an iterator from the list itself which assigns the next() element's value to the variable specified in the for loop and this all happens on the C level, so it is much faster. All you have to do is access the loops variable which is just a little bit faster than accessing an indexed element of a list. This is because random access to the list elements will be performed part in Python and better part on C level.

So, if you do not have to change anything, but only need access to the elements, iterate over the list. If you are making in-place changes, then use indices.
If you need both, as in, you need to skip some elements or something, best way to go about it is:

```
new_list = []
x = 0
for element in the_list:
    if x%2==0:
        new_list.append(element)
    x += 1
```

Of course, this is just a stupid example. There is much better and faster way in Python to perform the task the loop above does. Some might argue that I could have used enumerate() for the example above, but I find this way cleaner and faster.